# Read HTTPResponse in Ajax?

Tags: ajax, json, request

I would like to send a simple HTTPResponse from Django. My code ist the following:

```
   jsonMessage = {
        "message": "Works",
    }
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(jsonMessage), mimetype='application/json')
```

At the client I just get HTML Code and do not know how to handle it. I guess that the client is the problem.
My code:

```
$.ajax({
    'url': path,
    'type': method,
    'data': data,
    'cache': false,
    'processData': false,
    'contentType': false,
    'headers': {
            'X-CSRFToken': $.cookie('csrftoken')
        },
    'success': function(data) {
    },

}).done(function(response,status, jqXHR ) {
    alert(response);
  });
```

The server side works well. But the response is HTML Code not the text I would like to get. I tried also response.message. But this is undefined. I think that I should parse the JSON Code. But I am not sure where it is delivered.Hope you can help me,

Comment: "But the response is HTML Code" — What HTML code?

Comment: "I tried also response.message. But this is undefined" — Since the response is HTML that is expected.

Comment: "I think that I should parse the JSON Code." — jQuery will do that for you automatically, if it gets JSON (with the right MIME type)

Comment: The Django code you included doesn't seem to be being hit. Check the Net tab of your developer tools. Check that the request you are trying to make is the request that is actually being made. Debug the python to get it to return what you want.

Comment: Ok, it seems to be the HTML Code of the page that executes the script.

Comment: That suggests you've got the `path` variable set wrong.

Comment: No it is executed. I checked it right now. Do I need to add datatype: 'json' in Ajax?

Comment: After adding dataType I get this error from the server: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <: 200; OK

Comment: `dataType` tells jQuery to ignore the Content-Type header. Since you've said the server is returning HTML, forcing jQuery to parse it as JSON means that erroring on the `<` is expected.

Comment: The problem is either that your python is wrong or your URL is wrong.

Comment: My python works if I do not add dataType. Otherwise it does not work. Do I have to add something on the server to handle the json request?

Comment: "My python works if I do not add dataType" — You said it returned HTML. If it is supposed to return JSON then that doesn't sound like it is working to me.

Comment: You have code on the sever for making a JSON response. there isn't enough information in your question to tell why it isn't working.

Comment: I changed HTTPResponse to HttpResponse("Text only, please.", content_type="text/plain"). This does also return HTML Text.

Comment: Either that isn't being called or something else is overriding it.

Comment: How can I check if it is called? I am using Chrome for development.

Comment: Print some debug data to STDERR and look at wherever on your server that gets output to. The console if you're using Django's built-in webserver.

Comment: I tried to use print('Test') inside this function. But it will not be shown at the console. So I guess that there is a problem. Any idea how to find out why it is not exected? I expect a internal server error with code 500.

Comment: Start at the beginning. Triple check the URL. Get Django to tell you what route is being executed. Follow the code through adding debug statements as needed.

Comment: Got the error. The form used this but this was undefined. Thank you so much. You helped me.

Answer (score -1):

Please make sure that the path to your views.py function call is correct,

```
$.ajax({
                 type:"GET",
                 url:"/djangoapp/djangomethod",
                 contentType:'application/json; charset=utf-8'
             }).done(function(msg){
                 console.log(msg.message);

               })
               .fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
                 console.log('failed');         
               });
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace your ajax code with below ajax code:-

```
$,ajax({
    'url': path,
    'type': method,
    'data': data,
    'cache': false,
    'processData': false,
    'contentType': false,
    'headers': {
        'X-CSRFToken': $.cookie('csrftoken')
    },
    success: function( data, textStatus, jQxhr ){
       $('#response pre').html( JSON.stringify( data ) );
    },
   error: function( jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown ){
       console.log( errorThrown );
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not work. It is still HTML Code delivered.